# Make rule in makefile always succeed

Tags: bash, go, makefile

Here is my makefile for my golang project:

```
.PHONY: killall

run: install
   ./bin/chunkserver&; ./bin/master&

install: clean
    go install godfs/chunkserver godfs/master

clean: killall
    rm -f bin/master bin/chunkserver

killall:
    kill -9 $$(lsof -t bin/* 2>/dev/null) 2>/dev/null
```

When I run `make install` it shows this error:

```
make: *** [killall] Error 2
```

I need return some code to make to indicate that `killall` rule is always succeed, but I don`t know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell make to ignore errors in a recipe by prepending `-`:

```
-kill -9 $$(lsof -t bin/* 2>/dev/null) 2>/dev/null
```